# Error in MySql database code "resultDs.Tables"

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio and C# to make a simple course management system, but I have some problems when writing the course query function.

Error An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' was thrown for 'resultDs.Tables'

Below is my code

```
    private void SelectResultForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "select ca.id,c.name as coures_name,t.real_name as teacher_name,ca.course_time,ca.course_place,ca.max_num";
        sql += " from course_arrange ca,course c, teacher t where ca.course_id = c.id and ca.teacher_id = t.id";
        DataSet ds = SQLHelper.GetData(sql);
        courseArrangeGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        int firstArrangeId = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];


        sql = "select * from select_result where course_arrange_id" + firstArrangeId;
        DataSet resultDs = SQLHelper.GetData(sql);
        ResultGridView.DataSource = resultDs.Tables[0];//error
    }
```

I have hit a breakpoint at this place and resultDs.Tables is null. But I checked the database connection are no problem.

I'm a rookie, I hope everyone can give me some advice

Comment: What is the code for `SQLHelper.GetData`? You have a syntax error `where course_arrange_id" + firstArrangeId;` is missing a `=`, and it has **dangerous** SQL injection. Also why use the old comma-join syntax rather than the much clearer explicit `join ... on` syntax?

Comment: Since I'm a beginner, I'm practicing according to the tutorial. What you said will be added later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Charlieface said, you have an error in your sql syntax. You need to change `where course_arrange_id" + firstArrangeId` to `where course_arrange_id=" + firstArrangeId.`

Of course, this is not necessarily the cause of this error. If you are sure that your database connection is fine, you can run with a breakpoint at `ResultGridView.DataSource = resultDs.Tables[0];` and then see the value of resultDs. If the values of resultDs are all null, you need to check whether there is a problem with your sql statement. You can put your sql into the database management tool to see if it can run successfully.

If all this is ok you need to give the code for `SQLHelper.GetData`. This makes it easier to analyze the problem.

At the same time, it is necessary to prevent SQL injection. If you are just doing simple exercises, you can use the method of parameter filtering.

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked the splicing of SQL before to make sure there is no problem. But when I checked again according to your hint, I found that the attribute name was misspelled. Thank you for your reply, I was so careless

Comment: @Willian you shouldn't be "splicing" SQL, you need to use proper parameterization

Comment: Yes, I will add it later. This is just a simple example